# How to change limits of y-axis? `ylim` does not work

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

When the graph below is plotted, NSS1 which is simply a constant set equal to one is right on the top border of the graph and thus hard to see.

How can I change the length of the y-axis to say 1.2 so that the NSS1 can be seen more clearly?

```
lambda=5;
tau=0:30;

tau(1)=0.000001;

NSS1=1*ones(1,31);
NSS2=(1-exp(-tau/lambda))./(tau/lambda);
NSS3=((1-exp(-tau/lambda))./(tau/lambda)-exp(-tau/lambda));

%ylim([0, 1.2])
plot(tau,NSS1,'-k*',tau,NSS2,'-k+',tau,NSS3,'-ko');
xlabel('t = 0 to 30y', 'FontSize',30)
ylabel('yield','FontSize',30)
```

Comment: You have the answer commented in your code...ylim([0 1.2])

Comment: Sorry I meant to say I tried that but it doesn't seem to be work?

Comment: oh ok. Try putting the line after the call to plot; that should work

Answer (score 3):

The reason why `ylim` doesn't work if you put it **before** the plot command is that there is no `axes` object it can relate to.

So there are **two options**:

First, you create an `axes` object and hold it with `hold on`, so the upcoming `plot` is plotted on the same axis.

```
ax = axes; hold on;
ylim([0, 1.2])

plot(tau,NSS1,'-k*',tau,NSS2,'-k+',tau,NSS3,'-ko');
```

or second, you `plot` first, the command automatically generates an `axes` object and you can modify its y-limits afterwards:

```
plot(tau,NSS1,'-k*',tau,NSS2,'-k+',tau,NSS3,'-ko');
ylim([0, 1.2])
```